# Xelatex on TexStudio whith tkz-fct package problems

Tags: xetex, texstudio, tkz-fct

When I use tkz-fct to build functions graphics in TexStudio using xelatex, the graphic dont´t appear, but when I use the same code on overleaf, It show me already whithout problems.

Someone knows what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: tkz-fct uses gnuplot, so it's quite possible that gnuplot isn't found in TexStudio. Have you looked at the .log file